# Matching domains with regex for lighttpd mod_evhost (www.domain.com / domain.com / sub.domain.com)

Tags: regex, webserver, lighttpd

I'm playing about with [lighttpd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighttpd) on a small virtual private server. I two domains pointing to the server. I am using the latest version of lighttpd and mod_evhost on Ubuntu 8.10.

1. I'm trying to set up a rule such that if anyone requests **domain.com**  or **www.domain.com** they get served from */webroot/domain.com/www/*
2. Similarly, if anyone requests **sub.domain.com** they get served from */webroot/domain.com/sub/*
3. If people requests **fake.domain.com** (where */webroot/domain.com/fake/* does not exist) I would like them served from */webroot/domain.com/www/*

The third requirement isn't quite so important, I can deal with people requesting subdomains that don't exist being served from the server document root of */webroot/server.com/www/* even if they requested **fake.domain.com**

I've included the relevant parts of my lighttpd.conf file below:

```
server.document-root = "/webroot/server.com/www/"

// regex to match sub.domain.com
$HTTP["host"] =~ "\b[a-zA-Z]\w*\.\b[a-zA-Z]\w*\.\b[a-zA-Z]\w*" {
    evhost.path-pattern = "/webroot/%0/%3/"    
}

// regex to match domain.com    
$HTTP["host"] =~ "\b[a-zA-Z]\w*\.\b[a-zA-Z]\w*" {
    evhost.path-pattern = "/webroot/%0/www/"    
}
```

So where am I going wrong? At the moment, all requests to ***.domain.com** and **domain.com** are being served from */webroot/domain.com/www/*

I'd appreciate any help you guys could offer and if I've left anything relevant out please tell me!

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: I've modified my answer to adapt it for your (optional) requirement No. 3. I can't test it, so would you mind to try out if that works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regexes seem to be a bit overdone.

Here is what I would use:

```
// regex to match sub.domain.com
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$" {
    evhost.path-pattern = "/webroot/%0/%3/"    
}

// regex to match domain.com    
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^[^.]+\.[^.]+$" {
    evhost.path-pattern = "/webroot/%0/www/"    
}
```

where:

```
[^.]+ matches anything but a dot, 1..n times
```

To match only valid sub domains with fall back to "www", you can use this:

```
// default: route everything to "www"
$HTTP["host"] =~ "([^.]+\.)?domain\.com$" {
    evhost.path-pattern = "/webroot/%0/www/"
}

// specific regex overwrites "path-pattern" for valid sub-domains only
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(valid1|valid2|sub)\.domain\.com$" {
    evhost.path-pattern = "/webroot/%0/%3/"    
}
```

Comment: Isn't it kind bad practice to make a regex that will match invalid URL characters?

Comment: It would be trivial to amend the regex to match only valid domains. I'll insert another bit of code to illustrate.

Comment: Apart from that: If this code runs, the requests have made it to your server. They'll very probably have no invalid characters in their host header.

Comment: @Tomalak I would be worried about using invalid characters on purpose for malicious intends like “/” or “..”. Though, testing that, lighttpd rejects those as bad request, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @jpath It depends on the HTTP server used, but I would not be surprised when most of them have some sort of built-in protection against path traversal.  But it never hurts to double-check, or to play it safe with the regex.

Answer (score 1):

For your first one, matching **domain.com** and **www.domain.com**: `^\b([wW]{3}\.)?[\w\d]*\.com\b$`, and for the second one, I am unsure if regex can determine if a subdomain/page exists, as it is for identifying strings of text of interest.  Hopefully that will help you out a bit.